# mysql query efficiency pulling distinct records from similar groups

Tags: mysql

I'm building a table that shows instances where more than 1 record contains the same `btc`, but for different `customer_names`, also showing me the lowest instance of `cost` for each customer.

This query works - but it's very inefficient and it takes over a minute to run on an 80,000 row table - so I feel I must be doing something wrong.

```
select btc,customer_name,min(cost) from table where table.btc in
 (select btc from table group by 1 having count(distinct customer_name) > 1) 
 group by 1,2
```

This outputs a table like this:

```
+---------+---------------+---------+
|   btc   | customer_name |  cost   |
+---------+---------------+---------+
| asd32   | Sony          | 1.45863 |
| asd32   | Nintendo      | 1.84839 |
| bf33940 | Sony          | 2.49188 |
| bf33940 | Nintendo      | 2.49188 |
| a43c3f  | Sony          | 2.84142 |
| a43c3f  | Nintendo      | 2.45    |
| a43c3f  | Sega          | 2.689   |
+---------+---------------+---------+
```

I'd like to take this a step further and NOT include any result where the `cost` for both `customer_name` fields is the same, (so - removing btc `bf33940` from the above table since Sony and Nintendo have the same cost)

I'd also like to know if there is a more efficient way to do what I'm doing.

## Table Structure

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
|      field       |     type     | null | key | default |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
| btc              | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |
| mpn              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| supplier         | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| invoice          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| invoice_date     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |
| qtr              | varchar(5)   | YES  |     | NULL    |
| qty              | double(10,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| resale           | double(15,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| ext_resale       | double(15,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| cost             | double(15,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| ext_cost         | double(15,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| gpp              | double(15,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| project          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| team             | double(15,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| build_type       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |
| customer_name    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| customer_address | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| customer_type    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| customer_group   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| sps              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| fps              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| gps              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| hps              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
```

sample CSV file here:  https://ufile.io/os0as

Comment: Can you give the table structure? And some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to replace your `where...in` by a `join` though it's hard to say 
how much more efficient it'll be without testing.

Something like this:

```
select t1.btc, customer_name, min(cost)
from xxx t1
join (
  select btc
  from xxx
  group by btc
  having count(*) > 1
) t2 on t1.btc = t2.btc
group by t1.btc, t1.customer_name
```

For your second question, you can further group by btc and cost to remove duplicates:

```
select t3.btc, group_concat(t3.customer_name), min_cost
from (
   select t1.btc, t1.customer_name, min(cost) as min_cost
   from xxx t1
   join (
      select btc
      from xxx
      group by btc
      having count(distinct customer_name) > 1
   ) t2 on t1.btc = t2.btc
) t3
group by t1.btc, t1.cost
```

Again, hard to say if that's going to work without testing, but hopefully you get the idea.

To make it faster I would make a separate table with each btc and a counter of how many customers have it, so you don't need to create a temp table with having count() > 1.

Comment: thanks!  I'm pulling back a syntax error on these SQL statements on the `) t2 on t2 on t1.btc = t2.btc` portion

Comment: @BrianPowell yes obviously it's a typo there is a "on t2" extra :) I edited my answer. As I said, it's not tested.

Comment: I hate SQL sometimes.  I'm getting an error now that `column btc is ambiguous`, but I'm not sure which of the 50 instances of me using this variable is ambiguous :)

Comment: @BrianPowell I edited my answer again trying to clarify, but you are the only one who can debug the query fully. It's not easy for me to write SQL blindly without a client to try it on.

Comment: Oh it's fine - I know debugging SQL remotely is really hard.  I appreciate the time you've spent helping me here!

Comment: @BrianPowell Glad I could help. If you manage to make the query work feel free to edit my answer with the correct syntax. And if it answers your question, I'd appreciate if you would mark it as accepted. If not, let me know what's wrong maybe I can help further.